# JFreeChart : Zoom-in for domain axis is not working when CategoryAxis is used

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using jfreechart library to draw a series chart. I have taken values on y-axis, time on x-axis and 3 categories as series. Everything is fine but I'm not able to zoom-in domain axis although it's working fine for range axis. Is this possible?

Following lines of code may help you to find some scenario of my code:

```
final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(true);
chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(true);
this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

and

```
//set plot specifications 
final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0xffffe0));
plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);

//CUSTOMIZE DOMAIN AXIS
final CategoryAxis domainAxis = (CategoryAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();

//customize domain label position
domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
       CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 6.0)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a `CategoryPlot` which does not support zooing on the domain range

[image]

To allow zooming on the Domain axis switch over to a `XYPlot` if you are using the chart factory the code is

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(...);
```

If you are able to cast the plot to an `CategoryPlot` something has gone wrong. I've checked `LineChartDemo3`  and this code causes an error (`java.lang.ClassCastException`):

```
try {
        final CategoryPlot cplot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @GrahmaA. If i can use anything other than CategoryPlot to display categories as series with domain zoom-in option?

Comment: @dirtyhandsphp if you can update you're post with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or point me in the direction of a [JFreeChart Demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) that shows the problem I'll investigate further.  In the JFreeChart demos LineChartDemo3 shows a 'XYPlot' with Categories is this a suitable solution ?

Comment: The only difference between my graph and LineChartDemo3 is that am using time on domain axis instead of numeric values.